# Copying variables from one picturebox to another without making them change with each other

Tags: c#, class, variables, copy, picturebox

I would like to copy a picturebox to another picturebox, but I do not want them to change with each other.

```
PictureBox picbox1 = new PictureBox();
PictureBox picbox2 = picbox1;

picbox1.Visible = false; //The problem here is that picbox2.Visible will also become false
```

I would like to make `picbox1` change without changing `picbox2`....

How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Are you after a [deep copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically) or are you trying to figure out how to make a picturebox have the same image as another?..

Comment: first you need to understand OOPS and then reference and value types and then how heap and stack based types actually works.

Comment: If you can say what is the core problem you're trying to solve that will be better for us to help rather than helping to clone the picturebox.

Comment: @Sayse not make them have the same image XD.... there r a few properties I would like to copy and I probably could write them all but that just felt wrong, I thought I could find a way but it seems like it would just be easier to copy them one by one... but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to maintain clean code is to create an extension method, also note that your second picturebox is currently not added to controls.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static PictureBox CreateNewWithAttributes(this PictureBox pb)
    {
        return new PictureBox { Image = pb.Image, Width = pb.Width };
    }
}

Picturebox p2 = p1.CreateNewWithAttributes();
this.Controls.Add(p2);
```

More can be read on extension methods [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
PictureBox p1 = new PictureBox();
PictureBox p2 = new PictureBox();
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(p1.Image);
p2.Image = b;
p1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: The problem was that i want more than one property, but i guess ill just copy them one by one then....

Comment: @AssemYounis If you to copy all properties you'll use reflection else copying manually is just fine.

Comment: ok so this link might help you.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12976/How-to-Clone-Serialize-Copy-Paste-a-Windows-Forms