# Anyway to duplicate a control?

Tags: c#, listview

Say I have a listview control in tabPage1 which has all preset property. Possible to copy all values and put it into tabPage2?

I am using the stupid method, which is

```
newlistview1.size=listview1.size
newlistview1.color=listview1.color
etc
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying variables from one picturebox to another without making them change with each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153434/copying-variables-from-one-picturebox-to-another-without-making-them-change-with)

Comment: sorry did not state that dynamically

Comment: Yes it need to be in sync

Comment: I assigned using newbutton1=button1 and now the button on my tabPage1 is missing

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473597/it-is-possible-to-copy-all-the-properties-of-a-certain-control-c-window-forms

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using 
    `System.Reflection`

[It is possible to copy all the properties of a certain control? (C# window forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473597/it-is-possible-to-copy-all-the-properties-of-a-certain-control-c-window-forms)

Hope this helps